# ruby version downgrade issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version

I have install rails 3.0.3 and 2.3.8 as well.So I have both version of rails.Now i want to use 2.3.8 version .But when I creating project its giving error ,and asking for using the command  :"rails new appname" . But this command create application in rails 3.0.3 version.

Can any one tell how i can set the rails version ,So I can use 2.3.8 as a default version for creating project on same version .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to downgrade Ruby (the programming language), or Rails (the web development framework)?

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend you use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) on *nix or [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) on Windows.

That's the current best (and painless) way to manage your Ruby environments.

You'll avoid precisely the sort of problem you are facing now.

For example, you can install many different Ruby versions, each with their own gems and you can switch to X version of Ruby like this:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 #begin using Ruby 1.9.2 and its gems
```